# How to get the authenticated user name under Apache using plain HTTP authentication and PHP?

Tags: php, apache, authentication

How to get the HTTP authenticated user name in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer you are looking for:

```
$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` if PHP run as an Apache module, and quite tricky with anything else

BTW, `phpinfo()` often helps with such matters

Comment: `echo "<pre>" . print_r($_SERVER, true) . "</pre>";` is also useful. Do, however, not use this on a live site (unless it's a non-linked file, and you *remember* to delete it afterwards) as there *might* be some important information in your `$_SERVER` variable that you don't want everyone to see.